# I need help to create a single line query from a single table

Tags: sql, database, database-design, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a table with column names 'department_name' and 'faculty_name'. A department can have multiple faculties. I want the query result to show the department_name and and the number of faculties on that department as a table in a single query. Is that possible? It was an interview question.

I tried obtaining department first and loop the department_name in the select query as below

```
SELECT count(faculty_name) from department_name
```

but it just returns count of faculties on only one department. I want the count of faculties for all departments

Comment: select department_name, count(faculty_name) from table group by department_name try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need  group by  department_name

```
SELECT department_name, count(faculty_name) 
from your_table 
group by department_name
```

Answer (score 1):

This query might work according to your query.
SELECT COUNT(faculty_name), department_name
FROM table_name
GROUP BY department_name;